# Example of a group $G$ that has a $\pi$-subgroup $U$ which isn't contained in any $\pi$ Hall subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to know if it is possible to find a group $G$ such that:

$G$ has a $\pi$-subgroup $U$ but $G$ has no $H$ $\pi$-Hall subgroup such that $U$ is contained in $H$, where $\pi$ is a set of primes, each of which divides $|G|$.

I know that this $G$, if it exists, is not solvable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is easy. Just take any example of a group with no Hall $\pi$-subgroup, such as $A_5$ with $\pi=\{3,5\}$, Then $U$ could be trivial, or a Sylow $3$- or $5$-subgroup. You could make the question more requiring by requiring that $G$ should have a Hall $\pi$-subgroup, but none containing $U$. (But there is still an example with $G=A_5$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, because  G is finite and any p-sub groupe U is  contined in a p-sylow of G, but the p-Slow is  a p-Hall sub group of G.

Comment: But my $U$ is not necessary a p-subgroup. My $U$ is a $\pi$ subgroup, with $\pi$ a set of primes that divide the order of $G$. Sorry I've not made clear the notation because I thought it was standard. I will edit the post.

Comment: sorry,  i thought this is a p latex error. and thinks,